# Protecting S3 assets from direct download

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have my assets (images/videos etc) stored in S3 and everything is working great.

The videos however need to be safe from download by the user. I have thought about numerous ways using Ajax and blobs and hiding context menus etc but would prefer a more simple but stronger technique.

The idea I've thought of is to add protection on the S3 bucket so that the assets can only be accessed from the website itself (an Iam role that the EC2 instance has access to).

Just unsure how this works. The bucket is set to static website hosting so everything is public in it, I'm guessing I need to change that then add some direct permissions. Has anyone done this or can anyone provide info on whether this is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serve video content through Amazon CloudFront, which serves content using video protocols rather than as file downloads. This can keep your content (mostly) safe.

See: [On-Demand and Live Streaming Video with CloudFront - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/on-demand-streaming-video.html)

You would then keep the videos private in S3, but use an *Origin Access Identity* that permits CloudFront to access the content and serve it to users.

Comment: Using this method seems plausible, I'm assuming I don't need to use a transcoder at this point as I can use the MP4 format. I was just trying to bypass cloudfront initially and do this directly in s3

Comment: If you serve directly from Amazon S3, then there is no way to stop them downloading the whole file.

Comment: What stops them taking the cloudfront URL and downloading the video that way? What do I have to do in cloudfront so that only the web app i've created can access the assets?.

Comment: @Kevin you can use signed URLs to ensure your website is the origin of the request and you can make the signed urls expirable (it will be valid only certain time) . However you cannot prevent client from storing downloaded or streamed content. Once the content reach the client, you are loosing control over the content itself

Comment: Bottom line: Even if you stream content, it is impossible to stop people saving a copy. There are utilities available that can specifically do this.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to already mentioned Cloudfront, you could also use AWS Elastic Transcoder (https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/) to convert video files to mpeg-dash or hls format (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP). These formats basically consists of short (for example 10s long) video parts allowing adaptive bitrate and making it much harder to download as 1 long video.

Comment: If I use mpeg dash I'll have to transcode the mpeg, I'm not sure how this works with the sonata media bundle as the filename that I've uploaded will have changed, is there no way directly in S3?

Answer (score 0):

For CloudFront to work with S3 static website endpoints, AWS generally recommends having a public read permissions on the S3 bucket. There is no native way of achieving security between CloudFront and S3 static website endpoint, however in this case, we can use a workaround to satisfy your use case.

By default, all the S3 resources are private, so only the AWS account that created the resources can access them. To allow read access to these objects from your website, you can add a bucket policy that allows s3:GetObject permission with a condition, using the aws:referer key, that the get request must originate from specific webpages. The following policy specifies the StringLike condition with the aws:Referer condition key.

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "http referer policy example",
   "Statement": [
     {
       "Sid": "Allow get requests referred by www.example.com and example.com.",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": "*",
       "Action": "s3:GetObject",
       "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
       "Condition": {
         "StringLike": {"aws:Referer": ["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
       }
     },
      {
        "Sid": "Explicit deny to ensure requests are allowed only from specific referer.",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
        "Condition": {
          "StringNotLike": {"aws:Referer": ["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
        }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Is cloud front a requirement for this?

Comment: Its not a requirement, I thought you’re going to use CloudFront as a front end. In that case, instead of using CF, you can directly use a referer condition in your bucket policy

Comment: If I can avoid cloudfront for now, purely for costs, that would be ideal. Cloudfront in future for sure. If using cloudfront does the referer need to be the cloudfront Addy? Or do I need to pass the referer through cloudfront to S3?

Comment: You would somehow need to create a wrapper/UI for S3 objects where you can inject the "referer" header in the HTTP request to S3. You can test the above setup either via Postman or using a curl with -H "Referer:https://example.com" flag in the request.